# Need help transforming one kind of list into another kind of list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list `(List<Row>)` of the following Row class:

```
public class Row
{
    public List<Field> fields { get; }

    public Row()
    {
        fields = new List<Field>();
    }

    public void AddField(Field field)
    {
        fields.Add(field);
    }
}

public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }

    public Field(string name, string value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

I want to transform this into a list of the following format `List<Document>`:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PubId { get; set; }
    public Date Date { get; set; }
}
```

Where "Id" is a incrementing counter and `PubId` corresponds to `Name: "PubId", Value: "SomeValue"` and Date corresponds to `Name: "Date", Value: "SomeDate"`.

I know that this can be done using LINQ but i just cant wrap my head around it!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var result = (sourceArray).Select(e=> new Document { DocProp = e.SourceProp, .... })`

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want something like

```
var docList = rowList.Select((r,i) => new Document
{
    Id = (i + 1).ToString(),
    PubId = r.fields.First(f => f.Name == "PubId").Value,
    Date = DateTime.Parse(r.fields.First(f => f.Name == "Date").Value)
}).ToList();
```

First off the `Select` overload I'm using includes the index and I assume you want the first `Id` to be 1 instead of 0.  Second the use of `First` is going to throw an exception if it does not find a `Field` with the specified `Name` (you might consider using `FirstOrDefault` instead, but that can be problematic for the "Date").  Finally if the `Value` for the "Date" `Field` is not a valid date then `DateTime.Parse` will throw and depending on the format you might need to use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Row> rows = GetRows();
int i =0;
List<Document> docs = rows.Select(r => new Document()
{ 
    Id = (i++).ToString(), 
    PubId = r.fields.Where(f => f.Name == "PubId").Select(f => f.Value).FirstOrDefault(), 
    Date = GetDate(r.fields.Where(f => f.Name == "Date").Select(f => f.Value).FirstOrDefault()) 
}).ToList();

public Date GetDate(string input)
{
  // Convert Here.
}
```